# How to redirect an entire directory to a different domain using .htaccess Apache Directives

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have the following directive in a .htaccess file in a directory off the document root called "redirect":

```
# 2014-05-12 redirects all/any pages in this directory to https://new.domain.com/forms/test/
Redirect 301 / https://new.domain.com/forms/test/index.php
```

Yet when I logon to `http://current.domain.com/redirect` (the home of the .htaccess file) the result is a page not found and the URL shows:

```
https://new.domain.com/forms/test/index.phpredirect
```

Why/how is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `mod_rewrite` instead of matching exact URI pattern as it support regex match.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /redirect/

RewriteRule ^$ https://new.domain.com/forms/test/index.php [L,R=301]
```